# 'User' has disconnected

Tags: wi-fi, tethering

I just received two scary messages on my phone LG VS980 running the Android Os

"[some name starting with H] has disconnected"
"MSN:[some name starting with H] has disconnected"
Back to back in like one second

How did they get connected in the first place? My Bluetooth is off 
I am on wifi, and the phone is charging via the USB port of my computer.

How can I determine if someone is connected to my phone, and what can they see?

Comment: Since you're on WiFi, I suspected "MSN" is for "Microsoft Messenger" and you're using an all-in-one messenger app?

Comment: No, that is what is freaking me out.  I have the default Messaging and Google hangout.  Neither actively running at the time.  I was in the middle of playing a game "Phase 10" when these two messages came across the bottom in the standard white text and black background.

Comment: and they don't match any of my contacts.  The name starting in H was something weird like Habryien or something.  Again clearly not in my contacts.

Comment: Then, my last guess is it's a notification from the game itself, indicating that a player has disconnected from the game. I have yet to test that, but if you can confirm, then it's good.

Comment: What kind of "messages"? Text messages? Notifications? Toasts? Messages inside some app? Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: @DanHulme by his explanation on the comment, *"two messages came across the bottom in the standard white text and black background."*, I guess it's a `Toast`, but screenshot definitely helps

Comment: @DanHulme I can't add a screen shot because it happen so fast.  It was like a notification message at the bottom of the screen but it is not in my notification screen.  I was in the app "Phase 10" to Andrew's point, the app doesn't have multiplayer however it was connected to google play.  For right now I change my profile settings.

Comment: Yes after looking for 'toast messages' this is what it looked like.